# C How to read from a binary file to a string?

Tags: c

I have the function bellow that reads a line from a file and saves it into a string regardless BUFF_SIZE length. I would like to expand its usage by making it capable of reading binary files. Is it possible to do this by only using the functions : open/read/malloc/free ?

```
static int read_to_stock(int const fd, char **stock){
   char   *buff;
   int  ret;

   if (fd < 0 || BUFF_SIZE < 0)
      return (-1);
   if (!(buff = (char *)malloc(sizeof(*buff) * (BUFF_SIZE + 1))))
      return (-1);
   ret = read(fd, buff, BUFF_SIZE);
   if (ret > 0)
   {
      buff[ret] = '\0';
      *stock = ft_strjoin(*stock, buff); //joins two strings
   }
   free(buff);
   return (ret);
}

int get_next_line(int const fd, char ** line){
   static char  *stock = NULL;
   char     *bn;
   int         ret;

   if (!stock && (stock = (char *)malloc(sizeof(*stock))) == NULL)
      return (-1);
   bn = ft_strchr(stock, '\n'); //search in string 'stock' for char '\n' and returns a pointer to it.
   while (bn == NULL)
   {
      ret = read_to_stock(fd, &stock);
      if (ret == 0)
         return (0);
      if (ret < 0)
         return (-1);
      else
         bn = ft_strchr(stock, '\n'); //search in string 'stock' for char '\n' and returns a pointer to it.
   }
   *line = ft_strsub(stock, 0, ft_strlen(stock) - ft_strlen(bn)); //subs-tracts a part of a string(string_from, starting_index, length)
   if (!*line)
      return (-1);
   stock = ft_strdup(bn + 1); //duplicate a string
   return (1);
}

int main(void){
   int  fd;
   char *line;

   fd = open("file1", O_RDONLY);
   while (get_next_line(fd, &line) > 0)
   {
      printf("%s\n", line);
   }
   close(fd);
   return (0);
}
```

Comment: You should take care about indentation: your code is hard to read. Whatever yes, reading binary or text files is not really different (well, it can depend, but nothing complicated here).

Comment: Are you seeing any problems with your code? If not what help do you need from SO users?

Comment: it's my 1st post here. please bare with me. thank you.

Comment: The code works just fine, but I need to expand the functionality of the function get_next_line as described above.

Comment: Well you question is about the difference beetween reading text or binary files. But your code is far more complicated and seems to come from an other project. So you should simplify/clarify your needs.

Comment: I mean several functions called here are not described. How can we guess what they do? But did you *have* problems reading binary data? The only problem I can see so far is that a binary file can contain `\n` (which is looked for by `ft_strchr` it seems) so the global logic of treating "lines separated by `\n`" is not suitable for binary stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading from binary files can definitely be performed via the functions `open`, `read`, `malloc`, `free` on platforms that support them, but be aware that binary files may contain `'\0'` bytes.

Therefore you cannot rely on the string functions that you use such as `ft_strchr`, `ft_join`, `printf` etc.  These handle C strings and will stop on embedded `'\0'` bytes.  You need to handle blocks of bytes directly, not C strings.

Furthermore, handling binary files as sequences of lines is not recommended: line endings may be transcoded by the runtime library: for instance CR LF pairs are converted to single `'\n'` bytes when reading files in text mode on Windows and vice versa when writing to `stdout` where text mode is the default. Other such transcoding may occur on other platforms.  Sadly, not every computer is a unix box.

Finally, even if no such transcoding occurs, the file may not end with a `'\n'` and adding one in the output may corrupt the file.